# Can I make a folder as a remote repository on Hostinger Server and push to it from local machine?

Tags: git, host

I have a domain on **[Hostinger](https://www.hostinger.com/)** I want to make a folder as **`a remote repository`** that can I push to it from **`local machine`** I know how to link Hostinger with Bitbucket and Github but the idea of question how I link remote repository on Hostinger with local machine directly.

Comment: @evolutionxbox yes, I use git every day

Comment: What do you mean by _"link remote repository on Hostinger with local machine directly"_? What do you mean by _"make a folder as a remote repository"_?

Comment: I have a folder on www.hostinger.com file manager, I want to make this a folder as a remote repository and push any changes that I make on local repository on my computer to remote repository on Hostinger

Comment: https://support.hostinger.com/en/articles/1583302-how-can-i-deploy-a-git-repository seems to answer your question? Use github as the remote repo, and you can setup auto deployment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used this solution to make a remote repository on [Hostinger](https://www.hostinger.com) file manager.

**First**

I login to Hostinger using **`SSH-Key`**

> `ssh -p 65002 username@IP-address-for-my-website`

For example

> `ssh -p 65002 u81299xx@185.200.81.1`

By default Hostinger use `Git` on the server I go to public folder then I create folder and initialize it

```
cd public_html/

mkdir mobileapp   

cd mobileapp/

git init
```

You should config `receive.denyCurrentBranch` for git on Hostinger server to update repository when pushing to it by writing this command

`git config --global receive.denyCurrentBranch updateInstead`

[image]

I added link to local repository, the link will be the same pattern of this command

```
git remote add origin ssh://username@Ip-address:@port/home/userName/domains/domainName/public_html/FolderName/.git
```

For example

```
git remote add origin ssh://u8144xx02x@185.203.52.1:65002/home/u8144xx02x/domains/example.com/public_html/mobileapp/.git
```

After adding link to local repository I push to remote repository on Hostinger server

`git push origin master`

Comment: You might run into issues using a non-bare remote repo

Comment: @evolutionxbox non-bare make issue when updating repository on remote and pull changes to local

Comment: I don't know what that means. I'm just letting you know that you might run into issues using a non-bare repo. The link I provided in my comment is more a flexible approach